# PHP/MySql search array with array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, wordpress

I'm building a WordPress website.

With a MySql Query I load all companies from my database that have a specific brand:

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'brand'")`
```

`brand` is an array so I search for a specific value in array:

```
$brand = $_GET['brand'];
$brandNeedle = $brand;

if(in_array($brandNeedle, $brand[0]))
```

Now, my client asked to list all users that are connected to all those companies that are selected.

So I need to create a new query. Fortunately the users all have a field added to their colum that tells me where they are working.

So I thought: what if I create a array that holds all companynames that are queried from the companylist.

With this array I can select all users who have the company name in their column

So I think the query should be something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM $wpdb->usermeta WHERE meta_key='company' AND meta_value ='THE ARRAY'
```

But this doesn't work obvious because it can't search with an array in an array.

I can't seem to figure it out. Any ideas?

-- EDIT -- 
Okay so I did the implode function and I do something wrong:

```
$brand_array = array();
for($i=0; $i <count($results); $i++){
    $result = $results[$i]; 
    if ($i % 2 == 0){
        $oddeven = 'even';
    }else{
        $oddeven = 'odd';
    }
    $post_id = $result->post_id;
    $company_name = get_post_meta($post_id, 'company_name', true); 
    $brand_array[] = $company_name;
}
    print_r($brand_array);
    $imploded = implode(',',$brand_array);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->usermeta WHERE meta_key='company' AND meta_value IN $imploded";
    $persons = $wpdb->get_results($query);
```

This gives me the results I need (the two companies in a new array)
and gives me the following error:

```
WordPress database error: [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
'brand1,brand2' at line 1]
SELECT * FROM wp_usermeta WHERE meta_key='company' AND meta_value IN
brand1,brand2
```

Comment: try to combine imploding the array values then use an IN clause in your query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you thought about using the "IN" clause on MySQL?
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in

You would probably have something like:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->usermeta." WHERE meta_key='company' AND meta_value IN ('".implode("', ', $brand)."')";
```

(**edit:** forgot to add the parenthesis around the "in" content)

Comment: No I haven't but I like it. So I still have to create a array that holds all my brandnames? Thank you for this push in the right direction! I'll come back if it works (or not)

Comment: yes, and you join your array using the "implode" function.
just remember to add quotes in your implode, otherwise the query will search for the whole string as one.

Comment: it seems that you forgot the quotes:

`SELECT * FROM wp_usermeta WHERE meta_key='company' AND meta_value IN 'brand1','brand2' `

just remember to add the quotes in the join as well, otherwise it will search as just one big string.

Comment: try like this:

`
$imploded = implode("','",$brand_array);

$query = "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->usermeta WHERE meta_key='company' AND meta_value IN '".$imploded."'";
`

Comment: What join??? LOL I'm over my head here, so please bare with me. I add the quotes in the `implode()` like this `implode("','",$brand_array);` and where do I `join` this?

Comment: Ah I see. Well the implode function does add the `'` now but still the same error message.

Comment: did you added the quote in the query as well? 

`...meta_key='company' AND meta_value IN '".$imploded."'"; ...`

Comment: Yes sir, I did. This is what I have: `$imploded = implode("','",$brand_array); $query = "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->usermeta WHERE meta_key='company' AND meta_value IN '".$imploded."'";`

Comment: print here your final query before executing it...

I think we forgot to add the parenthesis around the query: (I forgot it too)

`$imploded = implode("','",$brand_array); $query = "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->usermeta WHERE meta_key='company' AND meta_value IN ('".$imploded."')"`

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in

Comment: U are my new best friend. Thank you so much. This was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Search for mysql for IN clause

```
SELECT * FROM $wpdb->usermeta WHERE meta_key='company' AND meta_value IN implode(',',$brand_array)
```